# How to suppress the keystore password prompt when using Java Webstart with client auth?

Tags: java, passwords, java-web-start

Is there a way to suppress the password prompt when using Java Webstart with a https server that uses client authentication? I would like to do this, because the webstarted app runs on a touch screen device that got no keyboard and runs in a kiosk mode. Therefore it would be sufficient to either remove the password from the keystore or to store it somewhere, maybe in the desktop shortcut that starts the app.

I already tried to attach a JVM Parameter to the shortcut like this, but it doesn't work:

```
javaws -J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=mypass https://...
```

I also found out, when I activate the "use browser keystore"-option in the Java Control Panel and add the certificate to it, I can cancel the password prompt and still connect successfully. It seems like only the Java-Keystore asks for a password and Internet-Explorer's doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You try to use a custom KeystoreProvider implementation. It is not that hard to create and I assume that you could override the need for the password. You will need to customize the security.properties of the JRE that is used to launch the webstart application.

Although in your case ... is there a reason why you don't want to use the browser keystore ? In that case you don't have a problem.

David

Comment: I'll definitely take a look at the custom KeystoreProvide, thanks. The reason, why the browser's keystore doesn't solve my problem is this: When I use the browser's keystore, I still have to cancel the password dialog for the JVM Keystore. Beside this, the clients may be Linux installations and I haven't figured out, how the browser's keystore works there.

Comment: We used to use client authentication in our HTTPS commmunication but it seems that SUN is introducing new bugs with every release that we decide to stop using it. The latest 1.6 releases have a complete new Java Plugin (well you can even chose the version) with brand new regression bugs. It looks like client authentication is not very high on the list at SUN.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the Certificate Authority (CA)! If your webstart app is signed with a certificate approved by a CA already part of the JVM list of CA (Verisign, Thawte, ...) no password needed to add the app key to the local keystore.
So, if you want you can store manually in the Java default keystore your own Certificate Authority (will require a password once), and then sign you jars with a certificate issued from this private CA.
I don't know which JVM you use on your device (I had some issue with IBM JDK doing the above trick), but it should work!

Comment: I think you got that wrong. We talk about client authentication here. The server tells the javaws client, that a certificate is needed to authenticate. Then, the client wants to access the keystore, to look for a cert, that can be used for the server.

Comment: Ha OK! It's a two way cert needed, sorry.