# How to remove the password prompt from Java's trusted.clientcerts

Tags: java, certificate, keytool

I have imported a client certificate on the Java Control Panel and every time I go on the website that needs it the applet loads fine however Java prompts for the personal keystore password which I haven't set so I just click ok to dismiss it.

That does the trick however it's really annoying, how do I get rid of that password prompt?

my store is located at: C:\Users\admin\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.clientcerts

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to change the security level in the Java configuration panel?

Comment: Yes I did, lowered all the way, added site to exception list, allowed mixed-code, everything tuned but the stupid Java always prompts for the personal keystore password even though there isn't one and clicking OK or Cancel makes no difference, the Applet still works.

Comment: have to tried to use the default trusted certificates password? (changeit)

Comment: Are you certain that you're using the default trusted certs file in the JRE? you can verify this by logging the deployment.system.security.trusted.certs property.

Comment: Why are you securing your keystore? Isn't it a public key?

Comment: Also, I do remember there are issues if you're using a self-signed certificate (CA validation).

Comment: Yup, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799022/how-to-suppress-the-keystore-password-prompt-when-using-java-webstart-with-clien

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to enter a custom password or the default password, just cancelling the dialog works but it's annoying. I deleted the default trusted certs from my app data folder to have it recreated but the password prompt still shows. I'm not securing my keystore, never did, in fact not even my client certificate has a password. I'm running Java 6 in order to work better with my self signed certificate.

Comment: How do I use that "javaws -J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword"? I have an applet that loads on a web page, it's not visual and it's not a Java web start program that launches from a shortcut.

Comment: Can you tell us the purpose of using a client certificate? Are you validating a signed app? are you consuming (validation with certificate exchange) RMI services? I would like to clarify at which point the JRE is prompting for a password and its purpose.

Comment: Sure, I restrict the access to my website by issuing client certificates to the users, since the applet is hosted at the same server the JRE needs the client certificate loaded in order to download the JNLP and start the applet. The applet loads fine after I load the client certificate however Java keeps asking me for my personal key-store password every time the page that contains the Applet is loaded which is very annoying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55725/discussion-between-ra2085-and-paul-2011).